# Chrome workspaces with fingerprinted assets

Tags: css, google-chrome, bundling-and-minification, developer-tools, cassette

[Chrome workspaces](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/settings#workspace): let's say I map local CSS files to those served by my local http server. Everything works great and I can modify the files in-browser and upon page refresh my changes persist.

We happen to fingerprint our assets so that they are referenced via urls like `styles.css?longuniquehash`. Great practice - this way we can use aggressive caching and be sure the most recent assets will be used by the client.

However, this backfires a little with workspaces as the mappings get lost whenever the url is updated. In a nutshell: we map `styles.css?123` to the local resource, we change it and on page refresh it comes back as `styles.css?234` which has to be mapped again.

We're using [cassette](http://getcassette.net/), but the problem can be reproduced on any setup with fingerprinting. Is there a setting or a workaround I'm missing?

Comment: You can try playing around with http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/
However, it is not supported by cassette - the issue is still in open state.
Also might be worth looking into chrome extension api - e.g. rewriting urls before they are requested..

Comment: @bushed: hmm, good point, I haven't thought of using sourcemaps for css in this scenario (less/sass maybe)!

Answer (score 1):

According to Chromium, the support for mapping URLs with query params (i.e. `style.css?123`) was only partial up until Chrome 49 - where it was removed completely.

If you can't manually remove the params from your code, a temporary workaround is to remove the `?123` param from the stylesheet reference in the Chrome inspector once the page has loaded. Then your workspace mapping and auto-refreshing should work fine until you load the page again.

You can star and follow this issue here: [bugs.chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=595347#c24)

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's useful! Changing the link href wouldn't work in this scenario since modifying it would see the resource re-loaded from the new url - and that url will not be cache busted.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you do not develop on your live server (and if you do please stop and develop on your local machine or at least on a test server) so you activate the "cache buster" only on your live environment. We always have a quick way of checking the environment we are running on all our projects so just check before appending the "?123" query. 
I you do not what to solve this in code you can also add this in your htacces (if you are using apache)

```
SetEnvIf Host 'local.domain.com' runenv=local

RewriteCond %{ENV:runenv} ^local$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.css
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```